# Sistema de notificaciones

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Tengo este modelo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero que el sistema siempre que un usuario crea un evento que me notifique a los demás usuarios, el evento creado y el nombre nombre del usuario que lo creo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No veo como empezar a implementar, estoy utilizando la version de python 3.6.0 y el Django-2.0.5.

Gracias

Comment: por favor, añade texto y no imágenes. Así será más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que empieces instalando [django-notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications). Es lo que suelo utilizar para este tipo de menesteres y te permite abstraer el tema de las notificaciones de cualquier modelo al que quieras asociarlo.

Una vez instalado, bastará con que uses `signals` para que cuando haya modificaciones o creaciones de `Event` crees la notificación pertinente. Por ejemplo:

```
# signals.py
...

@receiver(post_save, sender=models.Event)
def notify_event(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        notify.send(instance.author,
                    recipient=recipient,
                    verb='ha creado un evento',
                    target=instance)
```

Para más información en cuanto a `signals`, puedes echar un vistazo [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/).